# Why isn't Hawking Radiation Neutral?

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

My understanding of Hawking Radiation is that it is a pair of virtual particles that pop into existence at the edge of an even horizon.  The anti-particle falls into the event horizon thus slightly reducing the holes mass.

My question is this:  The anti particle will fall in 50% of the time...  Wouldn't that mean that 50% of the time, the regular particle falls in... thus adding the same amount of mass that was just deducted?

In some cases, couldn't a black hole increase in mass if just a tiny bit more regular particles fall in that anti- particles?

Comment: Anti-particles don't have negative mass. I've linked questions that discuss more accurate explanations of Hawking radiation than the virtual-pairs analogy as duplicates.

Comment: I think he means that if the antiparticle (positron) falls in and meets an electron it will annihilate creating energy - he maybe missing the point that mass/energy are equivalent.

Comment: @Drjh - No... I am trying to wrap my non scientific head around something that is not logical, but probably makes sense, mathematically.  How does a particle entering an event horizon bleed energy from a singularity?  If it's because of an anti-particle falling in, then the BH should never lose mass as a regular particle has the same chance of being captured.